# Using pywinauto for uninstalling a program (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, ui-automation, pywinauto

[Code snippet and resulting uninstaller window on execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EluY.png)

I am attempting to use Pywinauto to automate the uninstallation of 'Microsoft NET Framework' using a template provided by Vasily Ryabov. 
I am able to get to the point where I hit 'Uninstall' in the control panel and the corresponding Uninstaller shows up (please see image)

I can't figure out how to transfer control to the resulting window, select the 'Remove' radio button and click the 'Next' button.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to connect to the uninstaller app:

```
app = Application().connect(title=“Microsoft .NET Framework”)
```

Then you can list all possible elements identifiers:

```
app.Microsoft_NET_Framework.print_control_identifiers()
```

This is all described in the Getting Started Guide (find the link in main Readme).